# Magento bundled items filter by parent id

Tags: magento, collections, bundle, product

I'm trying to get a collection of selections but filtered on the parent product's id. The collection contains an attribute `parent_product_id` but apparently this isn't working... The filter is not taken into account.

This is what I have so far:

```
$children = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('product_id', 'selection_price_value'))
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_product_id',$item->getProductId());
```

It returns a collection of all selections, so without filter. Is there some way to get only the selections of one specific bundled product? Please note I am using this method for a reason... It should be only based on the parent id.

Comment: Look like you have not got an answer yet?

Comment: Not yet... although the 'hack' will probably work, I'm still hoping for a elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to check how the query is constructed by the collection:

```
$sql = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')->getSelect()->__toString(); 
Mage::log($sql);`
```

Check if your filter is really there (in the WHERE clause) and run the extracted SQL Query against your database (in PhpMyAdmin or mysql-client if you have shell access). You should see the source of the problem.

You could also try a **dirty** method, and mess whit the `Zend_Select` object of the collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('product_id', 'selection_price_value'))
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$collection->getSelect()->where('`selection`.`parent_product_id` = '.$item->getProductId());
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I could use that, but I really  prefer to do things the right Magento way... This more of a hack when magento fails, but it seems to me that a regular attribute-filter has to work. The query string was of course already tested, the where clause of the parent_product_id is never added.

Comment: It's really only a hack if you use the EAV model, or mess around with joins. Using ->where() on a flat table is probably the best way to filter flat collections.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*') //select all possible fields    
->addFieldToFilter('parent_product_id',array('eq' => $item->getProductId()));
```

Some fields are attributes, others are just fields within that table.

Look at this file for some samples:
/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php